# Export chart with datatable in primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, charts, export-to-pdf

i have one form inside the form i have one datatable and one chart so i need to export both in either PDF or excel file, i am using following command for export data

```
<h:form id="contenForm">
<!-- chart -->
<p:chart type="bar" model="#{dataModel.barModel}" id="barChart" />

<!-- Datatable -->
<p:dataTable  value="#{dataModel.list}" var="loc"  width="100%" paginator="true"
                        id="tableResulta" paginatorPosition="bottom" tableStyle="margin:0 auto; width:100%" rendered="#{not empty dataModel.list}">
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Surname" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{loc.surname}" />
        </p:column>
        <!-- and other colume-->
</p:dataTable>  

<!-- Export button -->
<h:panelGrid  columns="2"  rendered="#{not empty dataModel.list}">
    <h:commandLink immediate="true">
        <p:commandButton value="Export excel" immediate="true" />
        <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="barChart,tableResulta" fileName="formInformation" />
    </h:commandLink>
    <h:commandLink immediate="true">
        <p:commandButton value="Export PDF" immediate="true" />
        <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="barChart,tableResulta" fileName="formInformation" />
    </h:commandLink>
</h:panelGrid>

</h:form>
```

i have tried above code but not able to export both when i export only datatable then  its work properly.

so please help me how can i export chart and datatable into signle file?

thanks in advances.

Answer (score 0):

You just can't, not without creating a complex custom exporter... Sidenote: I think a real reporting tool is in the end a much better fit...

Comment: Do you have idea how can i create PDF as well as excel file with datatable and chart too gather?

Comment: can you please suggest me with example?

Comment: It could be possible to upload the chart image to the server in javascript and then add this image to the PDF in the preProcessPDF listener function of the dataExporter primefaces component?

Comment: Example: Check here: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+reporting+tool @lametaweb: Yes, and that is (part of) creating a complex custom exporter... Don t go there. Use a real reporting tool.